# Can the projection of two vectors be used to approximate the angle between them?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, angle

I am supposed to use a secondary justification (other than using the inverse cosine of the dot product divided by magnitude) that the angle between two vectors (117.429 degrees) is obtuse. The two vectors are:

A: <5,0,2>

B: <-6,2,5>

My secondary explanation was that the projection of A onto B contains more than half of the magnitude of B (e.g. 
     the magnitude of the projection of A onto B is less than 50 % 
different from the magnitude of B), 
 so the angle between the vectors is greater than 90 degrees.

$|\frac{Norm[Projection[X,Y]] - Norm[Y]}{Norm[Y]}|$ = 69.2%>50%

Does this make sense why the angle would be obtuse, and are there any counterexamples to this?

Comment: Since magnitude is always positive, a negative dot product produces an obtuse angle, since $\cos\theta<0$ when $\theta\in(\frac{\pi}2,\pi)$.

Comment: The magnitude of the projection is symmetric about the 90-degree mark (where the magnitude is zero!), so I doesn’t look to me like you can use only the magnitude to distinguish acute from obtuse angles.